# Tableau Legend Issue

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to use a legend(which is common for more than 2 columns)
such that

a. tick mark means 3

b. exclamation mark means 2

c. Bold circle means 1

See the screenshot  for 2 columns displayed in the attachment.

[image]

However i need a common legend for these columns

I tried to go to analysis tab and then click on legends, but this will show legend for only 1 column at a time and i need 1 legend for more than 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if the customization and formatting options for the built-in legends and filter controls don't do as you wish, the next approach is to build a worksheet that shows and acts as you desire. Then use that worksheet on your dashboard to serve a replacement for the built-in legends.

In your case, one approach is to make a simple text data source with one row for each item you want to appear in your new custom "legend". Then build the legend worksheet of your dreams :-)